# Import .txt file into Oracle table using Teradata SQL assistant

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

I have a table that use the following data types:

```
 CREATE TABLE Paper
( keyId            NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  version        VARCHAR2(255) )
```

I have exported another table to .txt file (ANSI-Delimited Text) with the information below:

```
keyId,version
417039,`1.1.0`
1032401,`3.5.0`
123328,`5.1.0`
3453791,`6.3.3`
43342467,`7.0.0`
54563,`1.0.0`
```

I then clicked on "File" > "Import Data" and ran the query below and selected the .txt file I exported previously:

```
INSERT INTO Paper ( keyId , version ) VALUES ( ? , ? )
```

and.. I get this error:

```
Error: executing query for record 1: 1008: ORA-01008: not all variables bound.
```

I made sure that when I am importing that I ignore the first row of the .txt file since it starts with the header columns.. What is my issue?

Comment: Did you specfy the correct delimiter in *Options->Import/Export*? Do you really want to import backticks?

Comment: @dnoeth I believe I did. I even tried it with a self-made text file removing the backticks. Any other suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try double-quotes.

Comment: I have tried that @access_granted, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to check 3 things while importing data using `SQL Assistant`.

1. *Tools -> Options -> Export/Import:*  Use this delimiter between
   columns
2. *Tools -> Options -> Export/Import:*  Enclose column Data in
3. *Tools -> Options -> Import:*  Skip Header

> **Sample Scenario:**

Current Settings:

1. In  *Tools -> Options -> Export/Import:*  Use this delimiter between
   columns: `,`
2. In  *Tools -> Options -> Export/Import:*  Enclose column Data in `Single Quotes`
3. In  *Tools -> Options -> Import:*  Skip Header `Checked`.

`Import.txt` file data has been modified as below.

```
'keyId','version'
'417039','1.1.0'
'1032401','3.5.0'
'123328','5.1.0'
'3453791','6.3.3'
'43342467','7.0.0'
'54563','1.0.0'
```

Then query was run after selecting *File -> Import Data* . Data is successfully loaded.

PFB screenshot FYR.

[image]

```
select * from Paper
```

**Result:**

```
keyId           |  version
--------------------------
3,453,791.00    |   6.3.3
43,342,467.00   |   7.0.0
1,032,401.00    |   3.5.0
54,563.00       |   1.0.0
417,039.00      |   1.1.0
123,328.00      |   5.1.0
```

Comment: Could you show me the statement you used to Create the table. Would like to know the data types. I am still having issues :(

Comment: @Dip: I used the statement you shared for table creation. Same datatypes are used.

Answer (score 0):

Not the same thing:

```
'417039','1.1.0' and 417039,`1.1.0`
```

single quotes vs forward quotes.